# XtraScheduler doubleclick

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Iam using DevExpress xtraScheduler 10.2

How to handle the double click event in xtraScheduler (just on appointment not cell)?

I dont want to show any appointmentedit form!

I need something like Hittest in xtraGrid.

And if i double click the appointment, is it possible to get the datasource object?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way. I think that is ok:

```
private void Scheduler_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Scheduler.SelectedAppointments != null) &&
            (Scheduler.SelectedAppointments.Count > 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hallo");
        }
    }
```

with this you can get the object of datasource:

```
 (myObject)Scheduler.SelectedAppointments[index].GetSourceObject(SchedulerStorage);
```